# How to make a DOM execution wait/reload for a JavaScript code to return a value?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I am struggling from the problem of page loading and base url.

I have the code below

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>VNavigator</title>

    <base href="/wrong-qa-url/">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (() => {
            /* To update the Base href*/
            let baseTag = document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0];
            let newVar = baseTag.setAttribute("href", 'new-url');

            // I have to wait till now and execute the rest page
        })()
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/meridian-sdk.js">
    </script>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.ba2c08d9d64b6377d8a3.css">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the script Tag to execute first then the other Tags like  should load.

What is the correct way to stop the DOm Execution and wait for a variable to come ?

Comment: put your scripts at the bottom of the page right below the ending </body> element

Comment: This looks like a XY problem to me. You are desperately trying to change the base href of an Angular application by developing your own hack, not succeeding, and asking people how your hack could work, when there is a correct way to do it : `ng build --base-href=newurl`. This changes the <base href> tag.

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks for understanding but the problem is a little broader. 

Actually the project code is not only angular it is inside a folder which is a backend code. 

Actually the base-href should be according to the URL loaded.

Not sure how I should handle this